# PHP equivelant of Perl's encrypt_hex

Tags: php, perl, cryptography

With PHP, I'm trying to emulate the Perl functionality of:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;
use Crypt::ECB qw(encrypt decrypt encrypt_hex decrypt_hex);
$code = encrypt_hex($key, "Blowfish", $secret);
```

My results haven't generated anything close, such as:

```
$code = crypt($key, '$2a$07$'."$secret$");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: @daxim, I'm not sure actually.  This is code I've inherited from a developer long since gone.  still works, though.  I've updated the perl part of the example to show the includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me some time to figure it out.  @daxim's use of mcrypt put me down the path of trying the mcrypt libraries.

```
$td = mcrypt_module_open('blowfish', '', 'ecb', '');
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
$encrypted_data = mcrypt_generic($td, $secret);
mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
mcrypt_module_close($td);

$unpacked = unpack("H*", $encrypted_data);
$hexed = implode($unpacked);
```

Answer (score 1):

Half an answer:

```
Crypt::ECB::encrypt_hex('Some_key', 'Blowfish', '12345678')
```

is supposed to be equivalent to

```
unpack('H*', mcrypt_ecb('BLOWFISH', 'Some_key', '12345678', MCRYPT_ENCRYPT))
```

I couldn't get it to work, though.

Comment: +1 for effort. I'm still trying to get mcrypt installed.  Will take a look at it again the next few days.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know about that PERL function, but maybe [the PHP hash-function](http://php.net/function.hash.php) does what you want:

```
string hash ( string $algo , string $data [, bool $raw_output = false ] )
```